# Is there a / how to solve this bug in OpenCV C++ kmeans() when using flag KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS?

Tags: c++, opencv, xdebug, k-means, flags

When I use this flag in OpenCV++ kmeans (see example code) the function does not change the labels at all. Using KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS or KMEANS_PP_CENTERS does work, the problem is only there when I use this flag. Increasing the number of attempts changes nothing. I'm using OpenCV version 3.45 (higher is not allowed) and Visual Studio Community 17 to compile this code. (C++ standard is unspecified.)

```
int main() {
    //voxelReconstruct();


    vector<Point2f> ground_voxels;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) ground_voxels.push_back(Point2f(rand() % 100, rand() % 100));

    vector<int> voxel_labels;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) voxel_labels.push_back(rand() % 4);

    vector<int> old_labels;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) old_labels.push_back(voxel_labels[i]);

    kmeans(ground_voxels, 4, voxel_labels, TermCriteria(2, 5000, 0.0001), 1, KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) if (voxel_labels[i] != old_labels[i]) cout << "okay\n";

    cout << "done\n";

    waitKey(100000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fixed the issue by creating an own kMeans() function, but of course that is no answer to this question therefore I'll leave it here.

Answer (score 0):

1. kmeans(.., 1,.. ). Set attempts >= 1, for example attempts = 100. Whats is attempts? Flag to specify the number of times the algorithm is executed using different initial labellings. The  lgorithm returns the labels that yield the best compactness (see the last function parameter).
2. Set TermCriteria type: TermCriteria::COUNT | EPS. Why do you use only epsilon but set and iterations?

Comment: Are you answering my question or asking me unrelated questions about irrelevant arguments? 1. The number of attempts here is 1, but as I said in my description, increasing this number changes nothing, 2. The constructor of TermCriteria requires epsilon to be the third argument (as far as I'm aware), and as performance is not the issue here and I do not have any errors, this is entirely irrelevant to the problem

Comment: I'm answering! Try to increase attempts count.